# How to generate page content from database the right way?

Tags: php, database, sql

I am creating many pages and store them into the database. I am first styling them and than storing them. The idea is to use page.php to check the page id and display the needed post. This is all good, but I have many pages in the website. WHich means I have to perform the following statement many time.

```
<?php        
 if(is_page(14)) {
   global $wpdb;
   $findContent = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT post_content  FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = 'Why ......'");
    get_template_part( 'localnav' );
    echo $findContent;
  }
?>
```

My question is is that a good rpactice or is there a better idea?
Note there asome pages which look alike, maybe I can create catogories, but is it possible to select part of the content and put it in a div for example?

Comment: But if it looks like that and I use the default template for a page, nothing is displayed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress is fetching current post for you, you have to only type to the right url. When you get e.g. to `example.com/lorem-ipsum/` WordPress will load automatically post with title `Lorem ipsum` and display it using `page.php` template. Your `page.php` template should be looking something like that.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="content">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(): ?>

            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

The concept of a loop is difficult to understand for novice developers. Only in the loop you can use functions like `the_title` or`the_content`. Outside of the `loop`, these functions won't return you anything.

https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop